# equivalence classes and partitions exercises

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let A= {1,2,3,4,5}x{1,2,3,4,5} and consider the equivalence relation R over A defined as:(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2) if and only if x_1 + y_1= x_2 + y_2; show all the equivalence classes of R and the partition induced by R
the problem I have is that my teacher said that there are 9 equivalence classes in this relation, and I only have one; please I would appreciate your help :)

Comment: There is certainly more than one equivalence class. For example, (1,2) is not equivalent to (3,3) because 1+2 is not equal to 3+3. On the other hand, the 25 elements of A are not in separate equivalence classes, because, for example, (3,4), (2,5), and (5,2) are all equivalent (and in the same equivalence class. Can you take things from there?

Comment: I´ve got 5 equivalence classes but all of them are the same because  the equivalence class of 1(which is {1,2,3,4,5}), is the same as the equivalence class of 2, and is equal to the equivalence classes of 3, 4 and 5, but I think that there is no more equivalence classes but the problem here is that my teacher said that there are 9 equivalence classes so I dont know if I am wrong or my teacher is wrong , what do you think?

Comment: What do you mean by "the equivalence class of 1"?  The elements of $A$ are _pairs_ of numbers.  It doesn't mean anything for a single number to be $R$-related to anything here.

Comment: I have the definition her it says that the equivalence class of [a]={x elements of X: a is related to x} (in this case X={1,2,3,4,5}) so the equivalence class of [1]={1,2,3,4,5} because 1 is related to all this numbers: (1,1), (1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5) are all in the equivalence relation R

Comment: Why would 1 be related to, say, 2?  The definition of $R$ doesn't say that.  I think you may be confused because formally speaking a relation is a set of ordered pairs of elements from its domain, and here the domain $A$ is also itself a set of ordered pairs, so that $R$ is a set of ordered pairs of ordered pairs.  _E.g._ $((2,5),(4,3)) \in R$.  (If this is not what is confusing you, then you can ignore what I just said.)

Comment: I think i see my mistake because i need to consider the ordered pairs instead of the numbers alone, is as you say :D

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Let $f$ be the function on the Cartesian product $\{1,2,3,4,5\} \times \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ defined by $f(x,y) = x+y$.  By the definition of the relation $R$, two pairs $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ are in the same $R$-equivalence class if and only if $f(x,y) = f(x',y')$; for example, $(2,5)$ and $(4,3)$ are in the same $R$-equivalence class because $f(2,5) = 7 = f(4,3)$.  The number of $R$-equivalence classes is the same as the number of possible values that the function $f$ can take.

Comment: So what my teacher said is correct there are 9 equivalence classes because there are 9 different values that the function can take but i only have 5 can you give me another hint for the other 4 classes i would really appreciate it

Comment: Yes, your teacher was correct.  My next hint is that the thing you think is an equivalence class is not an equivalence class.  It is not even a subset of the domain $\{1,2,3,4,5\} \times \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ of the equivalence relation!

Comment: yep is becuase i was considering just one element I think I can handle the exercise from here and again thanks for the help :D

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, and you're welcome.

Comment: And just one last question is ((1,1),(1,1)), ((2,2),(2,2)),((3,3),(3,3)), ((4,4),(4,4)) , ((5,5),(5,5)) are elements of the relation?

Comment: Yes, those are in $R$ by definition of $R$. This is a good thing because "everything in the domain is related to itself" is one of the conditions (called reflexivity) that a relation must satisfy in order to be called an equivalence relation.

Comment: so ((1,2),(1,2)) , ((1,2),(2,1)), ((2,1),(2,1)) and ((2,1),(1,2)) are elements of R, arent they?

Comment: Yep, those are in $R$ also.